# How to show a count of 0 in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a table that determines the number of orders that fall into different order size ranges. However, I need to display a count of 0 for the order size range of `1,001 and Above` and it isn't showing up when I run my query.

```
SELECT "Bucket", COUNT(*) AS "Order Count"
FROM
(SELECT CASE
   WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 100 THEN '0-100'
   WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 400 THEN '101-400'
   WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 800 THEN '401-800'
   WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 1000 THEN '801-1,000'
   ELSE '1,001 and Above'
FROM OrderTransactions O)
GROUP BY "Bucket"
ORDER BY "Bucket" ASC;
```

Comment: What is the desired format (layout) of the output? The query you have in your post doesn't make sense; you say "... and it isn't showing up when I run my query" but the only thing that would show up if you run that query would be an **error message**. You have a subquery where you select the result of a CASE expression, but you didn't give it an alias - so who is "Bucket" in the outer query? If you need help, don't change the query you are actually running - we should solve the problem you have, not new problems you create by changing the query when you post here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery to define the buckets and then a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.bucket, COUNT(ot.QuantityShres) AS "Order Count"
FROM (SELECT 0 as lower, 100 as upper, '0-100'  as bucket FROM dual
      SELECT 101, 400, '101-400' FROM dual
      . . .
     ) b LEFT JOIN
     OrderTransactions ot
     ON ot.QuantityShares BETWEEN b.lower AND b.upper
GROUP BY b.bucket
ORDER BY MIN(b.lower) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [UNPIVOT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)clause might make for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a table of your buckets then 'LEFT JOIN' your quantities to that.

```
    SELECT "Bucket", COUNT(*) AS "Order Count"
FROM 
(SELECT '0-100' As Bucket
 UNION
 SELECT '101-400' AS Bucket
 UNION
 SELECT '401-800' AS Bucket
 UNION
 SELECT '801-1,000') Buckets
 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT CASE
   WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 100 THEN '0-100'
   WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 400 THEN '101-400'
   WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 800 THEN '401-800'
   WHEN O.QuantityShares <= 1000 THEN '801-1,000'
   ELSE '1,001 and Above' END As Bucket
FROM OrderTransactions O) QTY
ON Buckets.Bucket = QTY.Bucket
GROUP BY Buckets.Bucket
ORDER BY Buckets.Bucket ASC;
```